# "for easing restrictions" or "for easing of restrictions"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, gerunds

Today, we often see news headlines like the below examples, and I wonder if there is any difference in nuance between "for easing restrictions" and "for easing of restrictions". Can anyone help me with this question, please.

Greek government unveils plan for easing restrictions.
https://knews.kathimerini.com.cy/en/news/greek-government-unveils-plan-for-easing-restrictions

Koike unveils road map for easing of restrictions in Tokyo
https://japantoday.com/category/national/Koike-unveils-road-map-for-easing-of-restrictions-in-Tokyo